# CITEXT: which solution I should use for tests with JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I need to test `psql` `citext` with `JUnit` using `hsqldb`

### Step 1

Use `liquibase` to set up `psql`-dialect to `hsqldb`

```
<changeSet id="5" author="ustimenko" context="QA">
    <comment>Modify test database to be case insensitive</comment>

    <sql>
        SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE;
        SET DATABASE COLLATION SQL_TEXT_UCC;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

### Step 2

Change column definition via JPA

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "citext")
private String email;
```

### Step 3

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks privilege: CITEXT
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: type not found or user lacks privilege: CITEXT
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTypeDefinition(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readColumnDefinitionOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readTableContentsSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTableBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

I tried to apply some number of solutions

### Solution 1

`jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test;sql.live_object=true` as url of database
Have the same result

### Solution 2

`SET DATABASE LIVE OBJECT` as part of `liquibase` changeset
Have syntax error at `LIVE` keyword. I made sure it via inmemory hsqldb console. But when alter table with `citext` field type is changed to `VARCHAR(3***)`

### Solution 3

Try to add `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?stringtype=unspecified` for my production datasource, but have the same result

### Solution 4

Play with `ddl-auto`, but have no needed results.

Can you, please, explain what I should do? I would not like to use separate psql database for tests purpose. Is there any solution to use in-memory to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use PostgreSQL case-insensitive comparison using the CITEX data type, which is case-insensitive string type. HSQLDB uses collation, which can be applied to the whole database or to a specific user-defined type. Define the CITEX type as follows, choosing the maximum character size of the columns using this type.

```
CREATE TYPE CITEX AS VARCHAR(200) COLLATE SQL_TEXT_UCC
```